# $scope value doesn't get updated in other controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm having a problem updating a value on my view. Let me show you my code with a little bit explanation of what is going on. I know the code is a litte bit messy since i have tried many code combinations right now.

I'm having this accCtrl controller

```
controllers.accCtrl = function($scope, sessionFactory){
    sessionFactory.isLoggedIn().then(function(data){
        console.log(data.logged_in);
        $scope.loggedIn = data.logged_in;
    });
    $scope.logOut = function(){
        sessionFactory.logOutUser().then(function(data){
            $scope.loggedIn = data.logged_in;
        });
    }
}
```

Console log out put is `false` and this variable $`scope.loggedIn` controls my html by showing or hiding login, register, my profile and log out buttons

```
<div ng-controller="accCtrl">
    {{loggedIn}}
        <ul>
        <li ng-hide="loggedIn">
            <a href="#/login">
                <b>Login</b>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li ng-hide="loggedIn">
            <a href="#/register" >
                <b>Register</b>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li ng-show="loggedIn" >
            <a href="#/my_profile">
                <b >My profile</b>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li ng-show="loggedIn"> 
            <a ng-click="logOut()">
                <b>Log out</b>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Now user tries to login so he click on login button, and login form is shown. This login functionality is written in loginCtrl

```
    controllers.loginCtrl = function($scope, $http, $location, $timeout, sessionFactory){
    $scope.loginUser = function () {
        $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: $location.protocol() + '://' + $location.host() + '/server/api/users/login',
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
            data : $.param({
                username : $scope.username,
                password : $scope.password
            })
        }).success(function(data){
                sessionFactory.isLoggedIn().then(function(data){
                    $scope.loggedIn = data.logged_in;
                });
                window.location.href="/#/home";
        });
    };
}
```

After he successfully logs in, he or she is redirected on home page, but the problem is that `$scope.loggedIn` variable in account controller isn't updated even doe that `console.log(data.logged_in)` in loginCtrl is seted as `true`

If user pressed log out button, everything works ok again, since i'm calling function inside accCtrl. So the only problem is when users logs in, because he is doing this in another controller.

Also here is my sessionFactory in case u wan't to see how i check if user is logged

```
app.factory('sessionFactory', ['$http', '$location', function($http, $location){
    var factory = {};

    factory.logOutUser = function(){
        return $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: $location.protocol() + '://' + $location.host() + '/server/api/users/logout'
        }).then(function successCallback(response){
            return response.data;
        },function errorCallback(response) {
            console.log('error logging out: ' + response);
        });
    }
    factory.isLoggedIn = function(){
        return $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: $location.protocol() + '://' + $location.host() + '/server/api/users/isLoggedIn'
        }).then(function successCallback(response){
            console.log(response.data);
            return response.data;
        },function errorCallback(response) {
            console.log('Checking login failed: ' + response);
        });
    }

    return factory;
}]);
```

my app.js

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute', 'ngAnimate', 'ui.sortable', 'ngFileUpload'])
app.config(function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider.
    when('/', {controller:'homeCtrl', templateUrl:'app/templates/home.html'}).
    when('/home', {controller:'homeCtrl', templateUrl:'app/templates/home.html'}).
    when('/contact', {controller:'contactCtrl', templateUrl:'app/templates/contact.html'}).
    when('/about_us', {controller:'aboutUsCtrl', templateUrl:'app/templates/aboutUs.html'}).
    when('/cookies', {controller:'cookiesCtrl', templateUrl:'app/templates/cookies.html'}).
    when('/faqs', {controller:'faqsCtrl', templateUrl:'app/templates/faqs.html'}).
    when('/register', {controller:'registerCtrl', templateUrl:'app/templates/register.html'}).
    when('/login', {controller:'loginCtrl', templateUrl:'app/templates/login.html'}).
    when('/my_profile', {controller:'myProfileCtrl', templateUrl:'app/templates/myProfile.html'}).
    when('/trade/:param1', {controller:'tradeCtrl', templateUrl:'app/templates/trade.html'}).
    when('/user/:param1', {controller:'userCtrl', templateUrl:'app/templates/user.html'}).
    when('/swap/:param1', {controller:'subCategoriesCtrl', templateUrl:'app/templates/subCategories.html'}).
    when('/swap/:param1/:param2', {controller:'products', templateUrl:'app/templates/products.html'}).
    when('/swap/:param1/:param2/:param3', {controller:'product', templateUrl:'app/templates/product.html'}).
    otherwise({ redirectTo: '/home'});
  });
```

I probably have to implement some watch or some similar function, but i really don't know how so i would appreciate if you help me out.

**Explained in pictures**

Login and register button is displayed
[image: Working as expected]

User clicks on login button and logins successfully, but buttons are not refreshed, because action is happening in loginCtrl, but buttons are in accCtrl

[image]

After hitting f5 in browser, buttons get properly updated in accCtrl.

[image]

**TLTR**

Once user logs in in `loginCtrl` i have to update `$scope.loggedIn` value in `accCtrl`

If you need any additional information, please let me know

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem occured because the controller in angularjs are initialized only once, unless you set it to reinitialize. Try alerting something in the `accCtrl`, it will alert only once even if you navigate to that page multiple times. Hitting `ctrl+f5` worked because it reinitialized your controller. You can simply use `$window.location.reload()` to reinitialize the controller. What `$window.location.reload()` does is it not only reloads your controller but your services as well. Since, you are using `ngRoute`, all i can think to reinitialize your controller is using `$window.location.reload();`

```
.success(function(data){
                sessionFactory.isLoggedIn().then(function(data){
                    $scope.loggedIn = data.logged_in;
                });
                window.location.reload(); //the only workaround i could find with ngroute as for now.
                window.location.href="/#/home";
        });
```

However using `ui.Router` i.e.,`$stateProvider` provides you the option of reinitializing your controller only which is as following.

```
.state('home', {
    url: '/home',
    templateUrl: 'templates/home.html',
    controller: 'accCtrl',
    reload: true //will reload controller when state is being access
});

$state.transitionTo($state.current, {}, { reload: true, inherit: true, notify: true });
```

and

```
$state.go('.', null, { reload: true });
```

will resolve the issue of reinitializing the controller which seems to be the problem for your question as for now.

Comment: Thx for answer, but i'm not using any state provides, yet. I have also added my app.js. Can you please create example how my code should look like. When something happens in loginCtrl i need to update my accCtrl...

Comment: did you try anything to reinitialize the accCtrl when your home.html page is accessed? similar to using $location.reload().

Comment: so if i get this right. Once user logs in i have to make $route.reload() on login controller, so accCtrl gets updated. But first i have to make .state for home page?

Comment: if you make state for homepage then using $state.transitionTo("home", {}, {inherit: false, reload: true, notify: true}); will do instead of using window.location.href="/#/home";. As, i said the problem is your controller initializing only once.

Comment: i think i using directive might solve the problem as well, let me work something out.

Comment: a ok, i'm slowly getting this angular stuff :) no i'm not using any state providers, also i would like to solve this without injecting new item in, so directive would be much appreciated.

Comment: Good job sir! Thank you, much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, you're making 2 mistakes regarding the `$scope.loggedIn` variable.

1) you are confused because console logs one false and one true value for `$scope.loggedIn`; This happens because promises are asynchronous and code keeps running after you demand session to log in.

```
sessionFactory.isLoggedIn().then(function(data){
    console.log(data);                     (2)
    $scope.loggedIn = data.logged_in;
    console.log($scope.loggedIn);          (3)
});
console.log($scope.loggedIn);              (1) <-- executes first before promise resolves
window.location.href="/#/home";
```

So the last in order but first in execution log yields false naturally, as long as the user was not logged before the promise started executing. After promise resolves it yields the data and true. More about promises [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) and [here](http://www.webdeveasy.com/javascript-promises-and-angularjs-q-service/).

2) You are changing angular variables with ajax requests and angular needs to be informed when you make changes to the scope out of angular framework. [One mechanism angular has for that](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/When-to-use-$scope.$apply()) is calling a digest cycle explicitly with `$rootScope.$apply()` or $scope.$apply(). I suggest you make that work on your service. If you want to use it in the controller something like this should do :

```
$http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: $location.protocol() + '://' + $location.host() + '/server/api/users/login',
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
    data : $.param({
        username : $scope.username,
        password : $scope.password
    })
}).success(function(data){
    ...
    $rootScope.$apply();
});
```

Comment: regarding point 1: yes i just moved from php to js and i must say, everything is upside down. I will read about promises.
regarding point 2.  $scope.$apply() doesn't work form me

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, the $http call already wraps up an $apply call... you should approach the login problem with a $watch on the loggedIn variable. I'll edit my answer later...

Comment: `$http` is an angular service, there should be no need to `$scope.$apply`, i'm surprised there's no exception being thrown. `$apply` is only meant to be used when things happen out of angulars scope, so in a jQuery event handler for example. Also `.success` and `.error` are deprecated, use `.then` and `.catch`.

Comment: of course exception where thrown if i tried to $apply. I still need solution for this issue